# What's the difference between these two left join sql queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

There are two tables: customers and orders. Customer can have one or more orders. I would like to understand the difference in terms of execution speed. Any ideas will be useful for me to understand it better. So, thanks in advance for everybody who answers.

1)

```
SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers`
 LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id`
 WHERE `orders`.`status` = 1
```

2)

```
SELECT `customers`.* FROM `customers`
 LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`id` AND `orders`.`status` = 1
```

Comment: **execution speed** - the two queries are not equivalent hence there is no sense in comparing speeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First one will act as `INNER JOIN`. When you filter the right table in `where` clause the non matching `NULL` records from right table will be filtered, because `anything` = `NULL` will fail

Second one will work as `LEFT JOIN`. In join condition `AND orders.status = 1`  says the records to be joined with left table

Regarding the question about performance, as I mentioned above both the queries are not same so you cannot compare the performance really

Answer (score 0):

The first turns into an `INNER JOIN`, because for non-matching rows, `orders.customer_id` is `NULL`.  Hence the `WHERE` clause will filter all of them out.